In my LAN-only environment, how can I reach a specific containers located in HAproxy backend by identifying traffic with a URL path then re-writing?
Setup Details (in case it matters - see image at bottom of post)
LAN-only environment
Podman containers
HAproxy as proxy running as root on host (not a container)
Goal
(see image to help)
On Laptop, in browser, be able to access container 1 by entering 192.168.1.12/app1, container 2 by 192.168.1.12/app2 unique paths.
What is working
On the laptop, intering IP with port, on all three containers works perfectly (ie. 192.168.1.12:8891)
What is NOT working
When I started trying to re-write the paths and hit the root of the individual servers, some re-writing was definitely working but only resulted in 503 and 400 style errors. I could never hit the login pages of the individual servers, even thought the URL presented in laptop browser shows that it should.
I have the following HAproxy config (with some leftover attempts in there as well but commented-out to show some things I've tried)
defaults
  mode http
  
frontend cntr1
  bind 0.0.0.0:80
  timeout client 60s
  # option forwardfor except 127.0.0.1

  acl is_cntr1 path_beg -i /cntr1/
  acl is_cntr1 path_beg -i /cntr1
  use_backend maut028892 if is_cntr1

backend maut028892
  timeout connect 10s
  timeout server 60s
 
  http-request replace-path /cntr1/, /\1
  
  #option forwardfor header x-client
  
  server cntr_1 127.0.0.1:8891


Here is an image of my setup to assist perhaps
Any tips, suggestions, ideas, etc, more than warmly appreciated!
UPDATE 241107.
I just thought about running curl -v which I think contains some important info.  The final page on browser is 503 error still, though.
$ curl -v 192.168.1.234/eddy
*   Trying 192.168.1.234:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.1.234 (192.168.1.234) port 80 (#0)
> GET /eddy HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.234
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< date: Fri, 08 Nov 2024 05:14:28 GMT
< server: Apache/2.4.62 (Debian)
< x-powered-by: PHP/8.1.29
< cache-control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private
< location: /s/dashboard
< expires: Fri, 08 Nov 2024 05:14:28 GMT
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='/s/dashboard'" />

        <title>Redirecting to /s/dashboard</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="/s/dashboard">/s/dashboard</a>.
    </body>
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.234 left intact




to whoever downvoted: please provide feedback what wayne can improve on his post or his question when do that. that way he can learn from his mistakes

I just edited this post for brevity and added an image which maybe will reduce downvotes, :)

I am pleased to report that according to murphy's law, I got it working the same day I spent all this time publishing this question, ha.  I'll edit above with 241108 tag with my configuration so others can see how I solved it.  Hope it helps :)

You're supposed to put the solution in an answer (and then eventually mark the question as answered).

Thanks much for tips.  my answer doesn't fit...only get 576 characters or so.  How to deal with that?  I'll mark it as answered though, thanks. - NEVERMIND. Figured it out.  I have to hit that 'answer your question' button etc etc.  Thanks much!

@wayneoutthere you can also accept your own answer by clicking the green checkmark on your answer

It turns out I didn't need a http-request replace-path or http-request set-path. Somehow this must have been messing up the connection to the server. How I got this going was with the following config, but I still need to figure out if there is a way to mask the hard-coded port number in the URL, but for now, it's perfectly functional so hope this helps. The thing I didn't realize is that an IP address is also a 'host'. I thought a host could only be a 'domain name' so you can use set-var to set a 'host variable' which is just crazy fantastic, so that can stay dynamic. Will show answer in next comment... Sample config from my .cfg file for Haproxy that made it work:
frontend mautic
    bind 0.0.0.0:80
    timeout client 60s

    # MAUTIC SERVER 1 - /cust1
    acl cust_1 path -m beg /cust1
    http-request set-var(txn.host) req.hdr(host) if cust_1
    http-request redirect location http://%[var(txn.host)]:8891 if cust_1

backend maut018891
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout server 60s
    server mautic-01 127.0.0.1:8891 check


